# Simple jQuery Slideshow Transitioning Between Slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a slideshow using jQuery, and everything is working as expected... except for transitions. As of right now, the slideshow goes through my divs and adds/removes imgs, until the end of slideshow (at which point, the slideshow "disappears"). This is all good. However, I wish to make the transition effect less jarring. This is what I have so far.

HTML:

```
<div class="slideShow" id="slideshow">
<div class="showImg">
    <img src="http://paulmarique.be/dropbox/img/01.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://paulmarique.be/dropbox/img/02.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://paulmarique.be/dropbox/img/03.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  text-align: center;
}

.slideShow > div:not(.showImg) {
  display: none;
}

.showImg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.slideShow {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

jQuery:

```
   $(function() {
     setTimeout(playSlideShow, 3000);

     function playSlideShow() {
       $('.showImg').removeClass('showImg').next('div').addClass('showImg');
   setTimeout(playSlideShow, 3000);
  }
 });
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGYKrO

It doesn't transition at all.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, but I'm sure somebody will point out a silly error on my part very quickly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Note: I should add that I do not want to use any plugin for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. The CSS `display` property cannot be transitioned, it either is or is not. You can however transition the `visibility` property along with `opacity` (for example) to get a nice transition effect. Hint: The transition declaration for `visibility` will have a duration of `0ms` and a different delay depending on the state of the element.
2. You are changing the CSS properties (via changes a class on your elements) of the `.showImg` element(s) but you added the `transition` declaration to the `.slideshow` element. You must apply the `transition` property to the element that is having its CSS changed.

Comment: Doh. I set opacity to 0, and put the transitions on both .showImg and div:not(.showImg). Thanks a bunch, you saved my monitor from being thrown out of the window!